# How to prove that: $\int_0^1f(x^n){\rm d}x \leq f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ if $f''(x)<0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

> Let $f(x)$ have $2$-order derivative over $[0,1]$, and $f''(x)<0$. Prove that the inequality That;
>   $$\int_0^1f(x^n){\rm d}x \leq f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

I was able to solve for the case $n=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $-f$ is convex, and by Jessen's inequality we have
\begin{align*}
-f\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx\right)\leq\int_{0}^{1}(-f)(x^{n})dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is concave  ($f''<0)$, any tangent line remains above the graph of $f$: for any $y,t\in[0,1]$
$$f(y) \leq f'(t)(y-t) +f(t).$$
Therefore, for any $t\in[0,1]$,
$$\int_0^1f(x^n)dx\leq \int_0^1\left(f'(t)(x^n-t) +f(t)\right)dx
=f'(t)\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-t\right)+f(t).$$
Finally, by setting $t=\frac{1}{n+1}$, we get
$$\int_0^1f(x^n)dx\leq f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$